# How to mutate dataframe in R of unequal length

Tags: r

I trying to mutate dataframe in R as shown below. The below code is working fine. The logic is the i need to create a new column which lags by 1 in column a.

New column `1d` will have values like 3,5,NA,7,8,NA (this values are lag by 1 in column a)

```
asd <- data.frame(x = c('g', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'h'), a = c(1,3, 5, 1, 7, 8), b = c(5,6,7, 8, 9, 5))
asd %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(`1d` = c(a[2:3], NA))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   x [2]
  x         a     b  `1d`
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 g         1     5     3
2 g         3     6     5
3 g         5     7    NA
4 h         1     8     7
5 h         7     9     8
6 h         8     5    NA
```

However when the length is unequal like below, there is a error

```
asd <- data.frame(x = c('g', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h'), a = c(1,3, 5, 1, 7, 8,6), b = c(5,6,7, 8, 9, 5,4))
asd %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(`1d` = c(a[2:4], NA))
Error in `mutate_cols()`:
! Problem with `mutate()` input `1d`.
x Input `1d` can't be recycled to size 3.
i Input `1d` is `c(a[2:4], NA)`.
i Input `1d` must be size 3 or 1, not 4.
i The error occurred in group 1: x = "g".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Expected output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   x [2]
  x         a     b  `1d`
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 g         1     5     3
2 g         3     6     5
3 g         5     7    NA
4 h         1     8     7
5 h         7     9     8
6 h         8     5     6
7 h         6     4    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lead`:

```r
asd %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(`1d` = lead(a))
# # A tibble: 7 × 4
# # Groups:   x [2]
#   x         a     b  `1d`
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 g         1     5     3
# 2 g         3     6     5
# 3 g         5     7    NA
# 4 h         1     8     7
# 5 h         7     9     8
# 6 h         8     5     6
# 7 h         6     4    NA
```

FYI, in vector-parlance, you said *"lags by 1 in column a"*, but a "lag" would have a rows value in `` `1d` `` be the same as the *previous* value in `a`, where what I think you're trying to get is the *next* value in `a`. For lead/lag operations, `dplyr::lead` and `dplyr::lag` (not to be confused with `stats::lag`, not the same) are your go-to functions, and `dplyr::lead` is what you need here.

Comment: i see. What if there are more rows and categories. It should be dynamic. here you have hardcoded it

Comment: Good question, see my edit @rakfn (you asked while I was typing it :-)

Comment: got it. But still you have hardcoded it (2:98), Is there way make it more dynamic. Because, here you are storing to ````ind````. This occupies memory correct?

Comment: How else are you going to generalize it? The only difference (memory-wise) between `ind <- 2:99` and referencing it twice versus `a[2:99]` and `length(2:99)` is that in the first, it takes up 98 ints in memory _once_ and references it twice; in the second, it creates 98 ints in memory anonymously (unnamed), and then creates it again unnamed, and soon after both memory allocations will be garbage collected (but until the GC is complete, you have _two_ instances of that `2:99` in memory. Are you dealing with a much much much larger problem than you need to worry about index vectors like this?

Comment: I just reread your question, stand by one ... use `lead`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your logic correctly, this is easily done using `ave`.

```
> transform(asd1, id=ave(a, x, FUN=\(x) c(x[-1], NA)))
  x a b id
1 g 1 5  3
2 g 3 6  5
3 g 5 7 NA
4 h 1 8  7
5 h 7 9  8
6 h 8 5 NA
> transform(asd2, id=ave(a, x, FUN=\(x) c(x[-1], NA)))
  x a b id
1 g 1 5  3
2 g 3 6  5
3 g 5 7 NA
4 h 1 8  7
5 h 7 9  8
6 h 8 5  6
7 h 6 4 NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(asd1)
structure(list(x = c("g", "g", "g", "h", "h", "h"), a = c(1, 
3, 5, 1, 7, 8), b = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
> dput(asd2)
structure(list(x = c("g", "g", "g", "h", "h", "h", "h"), a = c(1, 
3, 5, 1, 7, 8, 6), b = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```